# How to deal with linux kernel drivers (for newbies)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to undestand how to USE linux kernel drivers. One day I wrote linux kernel module for handling interrupts from gpio. Built it with "make" command and loaded it with "insmod" and it worked. But now I am trying to use this  [ov5642 camera driver](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/media/video/ov5642.c?v=3.1).I downloaded the source code. made "make" command in folder with sources and when it built I used "insmod" command to load it. It is now listed in already loaded modules list but I have got no idea how to get grabbed frames.
How can I make it work and access its output ?

Comment: You need to revise your title and opening statement; it's far too broad.  A camera driver would be part of the Video4Linux, V4L, subsystem, and also require support in userspace.

Comment: Ok. thanks for answer. Actually I want to know "what can I do with driver source code and how can I get to know how to use it from userspace??"

Answer (score 1):

In order to capture frames from the module, you need to "probe" your driver with a platform device (i.e. you have to create a platform device in order to call "ov5642_probe" function). If the probe function is being called, and ends successfully reaching to "return 0", you will get a print "Chip ID 0x5642 detected" in dmesg. (You can easily check weather the probe function is being called or not by putting a simple "printk(KERN ERR "### my probe function is being called")" at line number 935 in probe function and check in dmesg. If it is being called, you have to interface the camera properly in order to probe driver successfully.

If probe function fails (i.e. being called but not reaching till "return 0"), then there should be problem with reading the registers of ov5642. Check the i2c connections and power supplies of camera properly (and make sure its power on sequence is performed as mentioned in datasheet) if you get "Chip ID" other than 0x5642 or i2c read fails.

If the probe function is not being called, then you need to create a proper platform_device.

Assuming you are doing this on a custom board where ov5642 module is interfaced.

If you get "Chip ID 0x5642 detected" in dmesg, then you should try with "v4l-utils" package. There are many options available in v4l2-ctl command where you can set format, query capabilities, start stream, grab frame. If you are unable to install v4l-utils on your board, then, you should try https://gist.github.com/maxlapshin/1253534. You can also refer to Documentation/video4linux/ on lxr online or any kernel source offline if you are interested in developing a camera driver.

If you are a newbie, and you want to learn to deal with kernel drivers, refer to http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/ and specially platform driver documentation under Documentation/driver-model/platform.txt on lxr for creating and probing a platform driver.

Comment: Thak You for this information !
There is a lot of knowledge that make things clear

Comment: Unfortunately this is not enough. The mentioned friver by @SSeba is just a **sensor** driver, not a camera one. So, it means there is missed chain.

Comment: And better to use this tool: http://git.ideasonboard.org/yavta.git. It comes from one of maintainers of video-for-linux subsytem.

Comment: Hi, @userAndroid I am getting the Chip ID values correctly, but when it is trying to apply the initial settings on the camera it fails.. I am using Freescale driver : https://github.com/boundarydevices/linux-imx6/blob/boundary-imx_3.10.53_1.1.1_ga/drivers/media/platform/mxc/capture/ov5642.c Do you have any idea on it